# Conditional average of array in Excel VB

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to know an equivalent in VB code for:

```
'In Excel cell (for ex. xlSheet.Range("A1"))
{=Average(If(A1:A10="Text",B1:X10))} ' <---Equivalence of this written all in VB code, not in Excel
```

That is, calculate the average of an Excel matrix (for ex. B1 to X10 Excel range), with criteria, from VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Evaluate("=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A10=""test"",B1:U10))")
```

Don't forget to put double quotes after single quotes for text.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest this code for the issue:

```
Worksheets("Data1").Range("D2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A11, "E2<>0", B2:B11))
```

Other should be:

Suppose in `A1` you have written this formula, so in VBA code you can use something like this:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5,"NO WEEKDAY","")

Range("b2").Formula = "=A1"
```

Please change cell address as you need.